# I want to sort a dictionary descending by number and then ascending alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have this code

```
L = ['c', 'c', 'b', 'a','b']
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
x = Counter(L)
dict1 = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: -item[1])}
print(dict1)
```

It gives me `{'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}`

But I want it to return me this: `{'b': 2,'c': 2, 'a': 1}`

if I turn it into a list and use `sorted` It will return me this `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]` which is not what I want, because so, the list will lose the descending sort by number.

Comment: `sorted(Counter(L).items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1],t[0]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` and `c` have the same precedence since they have the same value. Thus, their order is maintained, and since `c` appeared first in `L`, it will also appear first in `x` and in the dict comprehension expression from it. If you want `b` to come before `c` you could explicitly add a secondary key to the `key` lambda:

```py
dict1 = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))}
# Here ---------------------------------------------------------------^
```